# запись в cookie не сохраняется

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, cookie

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]требуется передать значение в cookie

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">  
<!--<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="cookies.js"></script>
-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>


</head>

<body onload="checkCookie()">
        <script>
        // получает значение cookie
        function getCookie(cname) {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
            var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
            for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                    c = c.substring(1);
                }
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                    return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
            }
            return "";
        }

        // уcтанавливает cookie
        function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
            document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + 
            ";path=/";
            alert( document.cookie );
        }

        function checkCookie() {
            var user=getCookie("username");
            if (user != "") {
                alert("Welcome again " + user);
            } else {
               user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
               if (user != "" && user != null) {
                   setCookie("username", user, 30);
               }
            }

            console.log(user);
            alert( document.cookie );
        }

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: странный код. ставим value для ключа name, потом проверяем ключ nothing..

Comment: не работал с cookie. как правильно написать?

Comment: скиньте код, где нужно записывать данные в куки

Comment: а эт он и есть как бы, пытаюсь сохранить  значение ) но в перспективе хочу передавать token jwt.возможно не то подключаю

Comment: `decodeURIComponent` - а это там зачем?

Comment: не совсем знаю , проверить решил коментарий

Comment: у кого есть работающий вариант? , желательно через архир какой поделитесь. у меня не получается записать в cookie  значение на подобии document.cookie = "userName=Vasya"; или $.cookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value', {path: '/',});

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onload="checkCookie()">
    <script>
        // получает значение cookie
        function getCookie(cname) {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
            var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
            for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                    c = c.substring(1);
                }
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                    return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
            }
            return "";
        }

        // уcтанавливает cookie
        function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
            document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires +
            ";path=/";
        }

        function checkCookie() {
            var user=getCookie("username");
            if (user != "") {
                alert("Welcome again " + user);
            } else {
                user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
                if (user != "" && user != null) {
                    setCookie("username", user, 30);
                }
            }
            console.log(user);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: не сработало, прост в консоль вывелось что вводил

Comment: попробуй проверить в другом браузере. например в edge. если работает, значит в том браузере в котором не работает, запрещены кукисы

Comment: в хроме не работает, как исправить?

Comment: что делать ????

Comment: Включить куки для хрома) загуглите инструкцию.